# When should we upvote a question on Arqade?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting

The question I ask was first a question I had for any SE community. Naturally I make a research on this subject and find some very interesting Q&A :

- [Meta SE; Why arent people voting for questions ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions)
- [Meta SE; Why should I upvote a question ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/why-should-i-upvote-a-question)
- [Meta Arqade; Do you “sympathy upvote”?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3996/do-you-sympathy-upvote)

But what about Arqade ? While upvoting / downvoting an answer and the reasons for downvoting a question seems pretty clear, I have doubts about upvoting a question. For example :

- Should I upvote a question incredibly well written when I do not own the game ? In this case, I take the risk of upvoting a question (as good as it can be) that can states something wrong without having the possibility of knowing it.

Is there a list of the good reason(s) for upvoting a question specifically for Arqade ?

If you think this is a duplicate, please do not hesitate to tell and to provide  the Q&A I am looking for !

Comment: I always find questions about upvotes or downvotes a little pointless. We can say anything we want, but 99% of users are just going to do what they want. It seems like wasted discussion. Do we really need more than the tooltip already says, "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear."? If you can accurately judge that the question meets that criteria, upvote it! If you can't accurately judge it, don't vote! But we can say that all we want, and you're still going to see people say "+1 for a funny title"

Comment: I completely understand your point of view and you are right in my opinion (sadly I would say). But you said "If you can accurately judge that the question meets that criteria, upvote it!" and this is where my question apply I think: Is these criteria can be applied the same way on Arqade than on SO for example ? If not, what are the best criteria for Arqade ?

Comment: You should upvote when you know where your keys are.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first thing you need is a grasp of what is on and off topic. This is subjective, unfortunately, as different people have different views of what should be allowed. For purposes of upvoting, let's just say to avoid upvoting things that are blatantly off topic.

After you've determined that the question isn't blatantly off topic, the next criteria is, "Did I even consider upvoting this?" If so, then probably upvote it. That's it. If you thought it was interesting, or you want to know the answer, or even if the question elicited interesting answers, or whatever the reason, if it's not off topic and you enjoyed the question for any reason, give it an upvote.

Comment: It's pretty clear the way you say it, I valid your answer because when I read it, I think that can be applied for any SE sites regardless the subject.

Answer (score 5):

I'm much in line with @StrixVaria, but I'd thought I'd also add my thoughts.

The vast majority of my question upvotes fall into two categories: "That's interesting" and "I was wondering the same thing myself" (the latter, of course, being a proxy for "I was just about to ask that").  It's not hard for there to be overlap between these two categories.

What's "interesting" can be rather broad, but you can use the [hacker's guide to asking a question](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#intro) as a starting point.  I like problems that are hard, but not impossible, to solve, and present a problem that isn't just a case of RTFM.  The second category should be pretty self explanatory.

In addition to me finding a question interesting or being something that I'm curious about, it also needs to be on topic and well written (or easily edited to be well written).  If there are enough spelling and grammar errors that I give up on editing, then the question usually receives a downvote.  If I cannot understand what is being asked in the first place, the question receives a downvote.  If the question is just (subjectively) bad, it receives a downvote.

There is a huge middle ground here where a question is on topic and well written, but I just don't find it interesting, or it's not something I wanted to know.  I simply don't vote on those questions.  This includes simple Minecraft command block problems, or other basic questions where an answer isn't easily found in a wiki, and most questions for games I don't play.

Now these are just my personal guidelines, and they may not work for everyone.  What is interesting to one person probably isn't interesting to everyone else.

Comment: Your link is a very interesting guide, I strongly recommend it to everyone reading your answer.

Answer (score 2):

From [the help centre](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote):

> Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information. The more that people vote on a post, the more certain future visitors can be of the quality of information contained within that post – not to mention that upvotes are a great way to thank the author of a good post for the time and effort put into writing it!

I try to vote by the following method:

- Questions get an upvote if they are useful
- Questions get a downvote if they are not useful, or are very easy to answer with a quick search on Google
- Answers get an upvote if they are correct/useful/well-researched (any or all of these traits)
- Answers get a downvote if they are wrong or not an answer to the question

Also, I don't vote on everything... only questions/answers that stand out as "good" or "bad".  Of course, I am more likely to read questions that cover games/topics I am interested in.

There isn't anything wrong with voting on questions/answers that cover games you don't own... up or down.  A good number of answers are even made by members without ever playing the game (e.g. searching other sites for the information on behalf of the asker).

However, the way you vote is up to you.  You are not required to justify your votes.

Comment: If I completely get your answer, a downvote is (theoretically..) use for signaling to the authors that the Q or A need to be clarified, rewriting, in short : encourage him to apply the rules of SE. But an upvote is entirely based on your good will (based on the method you described)

Comment: @Fabien_M - I wouldn't say I vote to signal something to the author... but it is something I do to signal something to the community.  If I find something unclear I will add a comment, if I can correct some spelling mistakes or grammar problems I can edit the Q/A.

Comment: @Fabien_M - The overall point I am making is that there is no consistency in general voting.  There are no enforced guidelines, beyond "tactical voting".

Comment: @Fabien_M I don't know if this answer says that exactly, but what you've described is pretty much what my answer would say. I sometimes even leave a comment before downvoting, and wait to judge based on how they answer.